# MVC site not showing correctly on IE11 browser from IIS, it shows correctly when IE11 is called from .NET IDE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

My site works ok in Chrome and Firefox but i found some problems on IE11 from IIS (but it shows ok on IE11 when called from .NET IDE). main Menu page shows like this, as if it were taking a wrong Bootstrap version:

[image]

This is how the same site looks when called from IDE:
[image]
So this only happens on IE11, other browsers show this ok. This uses bootstrap 4.31, MVC 5. I don't think there is a real need to show it here since it doesn't look it's related to code (imo it has to be something IE11 specific) but i can add code in case it's needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Both screenshots have a different URL.  I'd suspect something about your local development environment is causing some resource to not load correctly (css?).  What does the networking tab of the browser developer tools tell you?

Comment: I always see differents URL when running from IDE vs running site when it's already published on IIS. Not really much info on dev tools, it isn't something specific it's all the webpages on the site are not showing correctly just on IE11 from IIS, nobody facing the same problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, the problem was because the browser was using IE7 compatibility mode. Fixed by adding this in headers:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=11">
```

More info about this:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do)